# Scala breakable function

Tags: scala

I have a function like this one: `def process(update:(Any) => Any, break:terminate)`

Class `terminate` :

```
class terminate()
{
  private var terminate = false

  def apply() = terminate = true

  def break() = terminate
}
```

Function `update` has a reference to object `break`, so it can call `break()` method of the same object function `process` gets.

Function `process` does some heavy expensive computations meanwhile calling `update()` with some progress updates and intermediate results.

As time of execution of the `process` function may be too long, `update` function may break the entire process using `terminate` class.

How should I exit `process()` (checking `if(break.break())` inside it) keeping best performance possible ? Meaning throwing exception is probably not the best option. Doing many `if` checks inside the `process()` is not good either. So what do you think ?

Any other solutions to this problem that do not use separate termination class to break a function call are appreciated.

Comment: This is hard to understand. Can you try to simplify generalize the problem you have?

Comment: i'd just throw an exception

Comment: What's wrong with exception?